# How can I configure Xcode to put '{' where I want it in generated files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, coding-style

I know this is a fairly contentious issue amongst programmers, but when developing I like my IDE to position the opening curly bracket underneath the method/interface/control declaration, for illustrative purposes: -

This is how Xcode automatically generates skeleton methods with the { at the end: -

```
-(void) isTrue:(BOOL)input {
    if(input) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This is how I like to lay out my code (which I believe is called the [Allman style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style_.28bsd_in_Emacs.29)): -

```
-(void) isTrue:(BOOL)input 
{
    if(input) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else 
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering if there's any configuration switch in Xcode to enable this style of development? It's really annoying when typing out `if`/`else` statements as it tends to auto-complete the `else` clause with the `{` at the end of the line which just looks silly if you like developing with them underneath.

Or am I being unreasonable? Is Objective-C supposed to adhere to a standard defined by Apple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at:

[Xcode: Adjusting indentation of auto-generated braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392749/xcode-adjusting-indentation-of-auto-generated-braces)

[Apple Xcode User Defaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html)

```
XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions = {
  BlockSeparator = "\\n";
  PreMethodDeclSpacing = "";
};
```

This should at least solve your problem after `if`, `for`, or `while` statements.

Answer (score 2):

After digesting the helpful information from WhirlWind above (thanks), the resulting snippet (just cut and paste into terminal) is:

> defaults write com.apple.Xcode
>   XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions -dict
>   BlockSeparator  "\\n"
>   PreMethodDeclSpacing ""

Stupid backslash quoting.  When typed at the terminal, there should be TWO exactly TWO backslashes in the block separator.

Comment: Yeah I got a bit confused about that, I did something similar to the above but used the -dict-add flag for each key/value pair

Answer (score 0):

Even with those settings, it does not appear to work with the templates. If you set this and then type "init" in a .m file you get:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    <#initializations#>
  }
  return self;
}
```

Note the "if (self) {" line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "defaults write com.apple.Xcode" doesn't work on the latest versions of Xcode (7.x)

Here are the solutions I know:

1. [Snippet Edit](http://cocoaholic.com/snippet_edit/) -- this little program will allow to edit default Xcode's code snippets. So, you will be able to open braces from new line in your `if`, `for`, `while`, etc. However, this doesn't allow to change the block indentation.
2. [Uncrustify](http://blog.manbolo.com/2015/05/14/code-beautifier-in-xcode) -- this might solve your problem too, but it doesn't look like being easy to set up. And it only formats the code **after** it is already written, instead of formatting **'on the go'**.