# Xcode 7: Change { (brace) location to start on a new line

Tags: xcode, format, xcode7, curly-braces, braces

I've read responses from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392749/xcode-adjusting-indentation-of-auto-generated-braces), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613599/how-can-i-configure-xcode-to-put-where-i-want-it-in-generated-files?lq=1), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120343/xcode-4-with-opening-brace-on-new-line?lq=1). I was wondering how one could do this in Xcode 7? I tried downloading Snippet Edit, but it doesn't seem to have the code for the built-in class methods stub like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
}
```