# How to change autocomplete braces in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4 with opening brace on new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120343/xcode-4-with-opening-brace-on-new-line)

I just want to change the braces style to

```
if (condition)
{

}
```

from the default style

```
if(condition) {
}
```

I cannot find the com.apple.Xcode plist after I installed the Xcode 4. So I'm not able to modify the xccodesenseformattingoptions BlockSeparator to \n.

Please help

Thankz in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets file, as detailed here: http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Put_that_where_it_might_belong_Xcode-PNL

I don't know if the same file will work in Xcode 4.3, but it's worth a try. Because everything is bundled up together now, the new location of the file you need to replace is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECodeSnippetLibrary.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets`.

Comment: Looks like the new file is now `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECodeSnippetLibrary.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets`.

Comment: Is that a different file? Looks the same to me.

Comment: No, you're completely right. Sorry about that - I was using the URL from the link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

For XCode 4 it's a little more complicated. See detailed answer here:

[Xcode 4 with opening brace on new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120343/xcode-4-with-opening-brace-on-new-line/5763379#5763379)

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 4.3.1 you must manually edit the snippets located at:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECodeSnippetLibrary.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets
```

There does not seem to be an easier way.