# CodeSense Formatting is not working for xCode4

Tags: xcode4

I typed both the codes in the terminal to bring the opening brace to new line.

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions -dict BlockSeparator " "

defaults write com.apple.Xcode XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions -dict-add BlockSeparator "\n"
```

Both these are not working for xcode4. What to do to bring the opening brace to new line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- this is broken in XCode4. Take a look at the post from Scott Forbes in
[Xcode 4 with opening brace on new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120343/xcode-4-with-opening-brace-on-new-line/5763379#5763379)