# XCode: change auto-completion for "if (...) {" to "if (...) [new line]{ "

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4 with opening brace on new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120343/xcode-4-with-opening-brace-on-new-line)

Is there a way to change the auto adding bracket to start from a new line? So:

```
if (a != 0) {
}
```

when { is added, it will be like:

```
if (a != 0)
{
}
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of tricky after Xcode 4.2. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5763379/609086) answer if you want to do it by yourself.

There is also an app called [Snippet Edit](http://cocoaholic.com/snippet_edit/) that can do it for you. But it's not free...